# How to keep a WebSocket connection to Heroku alive?

Tags: python, heroku, websocket

I have an Python Tornado app hosted at Heroku. It serves WebSocket connections and I want them to be kept alive for a long time (two hours). However, due to Heroku's limitations, it [terminates the connection after 55 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#timeouts) since the last byte received.
Possible solutions could be:

- Send keep-alive packets every 50 seconds
  I'd like to stay away from this option and use it in case there's **absolutely no** other option
- Include the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header in WebSocket requests
  Since the client is also written in Python, there's a way to include such a header in every request. And Heroku docs mentioned that such a header would stop the dyno from breaking the connection. But that doesn't seem to be the case - I've sent such a request and the connection was still shut down after a timeout.

Here's some code for reference.
This is the client part where the connection gets established:

```
req = HTTPRequest('server_url',
                  headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'})
self.conn = await websocket_connect(req, io_loop = self.ioloop)
```

And this is the Heroku log message:

```
at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/" 
host='app_url' request_id=some_id fwd="ip_address" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55003ms status=503 bytes=
```

How can I keep the connections alive?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [in their documentation about Websockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets#timeouts), a keep-alive packet is really the only solution for Websockets on Heroku.